# JQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Первый раз работаю с autocomplete, запутался в хлам. На сайте есть готовый код, который из БД тянет города согласно первых символов, после выбора города актируется чуть ниже выпадающий список и там выбор отделений почты согласно города. Я хочу что бы отделения выбирались аналогично города, методым тыка у меня все получилось, но мне надо фильтровать по ид города, то есть сейчас оно высыпает все отделения всех городов независимо от первого выше автокомплита.  Вот код достать города:

```
$(function() {
    $("#select-new-post-city").autocomplete("/ajax/getListData.php", {
        delay: 10,
        minChars: 1,
        matchSubset: 1,
        autoFill: true,
        matchContains: 1,
        cacheLength: 1,
        selectFirst: true,
        formatItem: liFormat,
        onItemSelect: selectItem,
        maxItemsToShow: 10,
        extraParams: {
            act: "getListCities"
        }
    });
});
```

Вот код достать адреса почты:

```
$(function() {
    $("#select-new-post-number").autocomplete("/ajax/getListData.php", {
        delay: 10,
        minChars: 1,
        matchSubset: 1,
        autoFill: true,
        matchContains: 1,
        cacheLength: 1,
        selectFirst: true,
        formatItem: liFormat,
        onItemSelect: selectItem,
        maxItemsToShow: 10,
        extraParams: {
            act: "getListNumber"
        }
    });
});
```

Как мне в адреса почты передать в POST ид города верхнего автокомплита?

Comment: что то мне кажется, что это не [jquery UI autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: эта штука, судя по всему, использует get-запрос, а не POST. Доп.параметры передаются через `extraParams`, Видимо, в обработчике `selectItem` первого списка вы должны получить значение выбранного элемента (из `li.extra[...]`), и потом задать это дело как доп.параметр для второго `x.setExtraParams(....)`

Comment: вот какая то документация по сему вопросу http://wiz-tec.ca/rpcl/autocomplete/autocomplete-docs.html а вот какая то статейка на тему https://habrahabr.ru/post/267191/ качество, правда, там страдает.

Comment: @teran Подскажите, пожалуйста, не могли бы вы написать ваши рекомендации в виде ответа?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я написал это в виде коммента, т.к. сам с данным плагином не знаком, и уточнял вообще у автор о том ли речь. нагулились различные форки из репозитриев, штука не очень современная. поэтому те доки, на которые я ссылался не факт что актуальные и вообще корректные. емнип. Да и чтобы грамотный ответ дать, надо все таки проверить это все на деле, а не просто прочитать одну статью.